# MongoDB return an object from $filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consumer field is array with two objects. With `$filter`, one object is removed but I need consumer to be object at the end, but now it is array with one object. I tried `$arrayToObject` but can't get to work. How to return consumer to be object?

```
   {
      $project: {
        messages: 1,
        authors: { $concatArrays: ["$userName", "$storeName"] },
        consumer: {
          $filter: {
            input: { $concatArrays: ["$userName", "$storeName"] },
            as: "authors",
            cond: { $ne: ["$$authors._id", req.user._id] }
          }
        },
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need $unwind

Comment: @Yahya thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
{
    $project: {
        messages: 1,
            authors: { $concatArrays: ["$userName", "$storeName"] },
        consumer: {
            $arrayElemAt: [{
                $filter: {
                    input: { $concatArrays: ["$userName", "$storeName"] },
                    as: "authors",
                    cond: { $ne: ["$$authors._id", req.user._id] }
                }
            }, 0]
        }
    }
}
```

You can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) directly right after `$filter` rather than an additional stage `$unwind`, `$filter` would usually return an array of matching objects or `[]` if nothing matched, So if you're using `$unwind` you need to use it `{ $unwind: { path: "$consumer", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }` otherwise there is a chance of loosing documents (Which has `consumer` as `[]`) in final aggregation response, Please read more about it here :: [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html). So I would prefer `$arrayElemAt` over `$unwind`.